# Saving array values for a secondary foreach loop

Tags: php, array, wordpress

Although used within the WordPress platform, this is PHP focussed question.

I have an array of child posts, some have content, some don't. My client wishes to display the posts in alphabetical order, but posts without content are to be positioned at the end (still in A-Z order).

My solution is to assign posts that lack content to an array, use `continue` to move the main array counter forward and then `foreach` over the the new array at the end:

```
<?php

    $child_pages = pp_get_child_pages();

    if ( count( $child_pages ) != 0 ) :

        $empty_child_pages = array();

        echo '<div class="row quick-links page-links primary-content-item">';

        foreach ( $child_pages as $post ) :

            setup_postdata( $post );

            if ( $post->post_content == "" ) {
                $empty_child_pages[] = $post;
                continue;
            }

            pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );

        endforeach;

        foreach ( $empty_child_pages as $post ) :

            setup_postdata( $post );

            pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );

        endforeach;

        echo '</div>';

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Would you modify the array during the initial loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest change I would make, speaking from a semantics standpoint, is to limit your whitespace and use consistent control structures. I.e. take

> ```
> <?php
>
>     $child_pages = pp_get_child_pages();
>
>     if ( count( $child_pages ) != 0 ) :
>
>         $empty_child_pages = array();
>
>         echo '<div class="row quick-links page-links primary-content-item">';
>
>         foreach ( $child_pages as $post ) :
>
>             setup_postdata( $post );
>
>             if ( $post->post_content == "" ) {
>                 $empty_child_pages[] = $post;
>                 continue;
>             }
>
>             pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );
>
>         endforeach;
>
>         foreach ( $empty_child_pages as $post ) :
>
>             setup_postdata( $post );
>
>             pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );
>
>         endforeach;
>
>         echo '</div>';
>
>     endif;
>
>     wp_reset_postdata();
>
> ?>
> ```

And write it more semantically:

```
<?php
    $child_pages = pp_get_child_pages();

    if ( count( $child_pages ) != 0 )
    {
        $empty_child_pages = array();
        echo '<div class="row quick-links page-links primary-content-item">';

        foreach ( $child_pages as $post )
        {
            setup_postdata( $post );

            if ( $post->post_content == "" )
            {
                $empty_child_pages[] = $post;
                continue;
            }

            pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );
        }

        foreach ( $empty_child_pages as $post )
        {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            pp_get_template_part( 'content', 'child-page' );
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

In my opinion, this makes it **far** easier to follow along with.

Comment: this is something I do need to straighten out, thank you, I like the formatting you've used. Do you feel I just leave my secondary foreach or is there something that can be done with the initial loop?

Comment: Not a problem my friend. Consistent code is one of the most important aspects of code.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems fine, assuming that the entries in `$child_pages` are the correct order. I mention that because you mentioned the ordering requirement in the description, but I don't see any supporting logic in the posted code.

---

If you need to sort the entries yourself, another solution can be sorting using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a custom comparator function:

- if the second post is empty, then the first is smaller
- else if the first part is empty, then the second is smaller
- else perform regular alphabetic comparison

Using such comparator, empty posts will get sorted to the end.

Comment: apologies for being too vague, they are arriving in the correct order. Thank you for the info on usort() though